# Prometheus - Query to show number of connected users over time

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I would like to create a Grafana graph showing the number of connected/active users over time.

My endpoint expose this metrics to Prometheus :

```
# Number of requests by userId
client_request_total{id="CkGe6t6JAD"} 65
client_request_total{id="ey7ECByJhr"} 3
client_request_total{id="ZhqNK297L1"} 6
client_request_total{id="rp6aUjB14I"} 3
client_request_total{id="OmrMoAVNoY"} 3
client_request_total{id="BNgmELRDE7"} 4`
```

For my case, a user is considered active if he has executed at least 1 request over a period of 5 minutes.

For example, here are 2 scraps

```
at 10:00:
client_request_total{id="A"} 6
client_request_total{id="B"} 3

at 10:05:
client_request_total{id="A"} 6
client_request_total{id="B"} 3

at 10:10
client_request_total{id="A"} 8
client_request_total{id="B"} 3
client_request_total{id="C"} 4
client_request_total{id="D"} 6
```

In this example, at 10:05, user A and C are active, and B is inactive.

So I would like to be able to create a graph that at 10:00
Here is what I would like to visualize in my graph:

```
10:00 => 2 active users
10:05 => 0 active users
10:10 => 3 active users
```

For potential cardinality issues, in my context there will be less than 100 users.

Do you have any proposed solutions ?

Thank you in advance.

I'm trying a combination of count / count by (id) / sum / increase without success

Comment: How are you selecting active users? I imagine something like `count(group by (id) (increase(client_request_total[1m])>0))` should do what you want, is it not?

Comment: From the frontend, the user identifier is injected into the HTTP header of REST requests.
On the backend side, an interceptor intercepts each request and does a +1 for each user identifier. (use of prom-client with a Counter metric "client_request_total" and a label "id" as client identifier)

Comment: I mean, how do you intend identifying by metric that user is active? Is it something like there were requests withing last 1 minute, or something else? Because your counter can stay at value 65 for an hour, and I assume you don't want to count it in.

Comment: Also, are you aware of the potential cardinality issues of your approach? https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels

Comment: For my case, a user is considered active if he has executed at least 1 request over a period of 5 minutes.
For potential cardinality issues, in my context there will be less than 100 users

Comment: Please [edit] you example into post: it's incomprehensible in comment format=( But query from my first comment with `5m` instead of `1m` should do exactly "at least 1 request over a period of 5 minutes."

Answer (score 0):

To get number of unique labels of time series that changed within some time rang you can use
`count(group by(label) (changes(metric[range])>0))` construction.

Here:

- `changes(metric[range])>0` gets number of changes of metric withing provided time range, and filter out those that didn't change,
- `group by(label) (...)` returns 1 for every unique `label` value present in inner query
- top level `count` simply counts number of results inside. Since `group` is use it also can be replaced with `sum`.

So, for this exact case query will be

```
count(group by (id) (changes(client_request_total[5m])>0))
```

---

Please notice, that function like `changes` or `increase` will work only for "initialized" metrics, so initial change from nothing -> `client_request_total{id="C"}` will not be accounted.
If it must be, replace `changes(client_request_total[5m])>0` with `changes(client_request_total[5m])>0 or (client_request_total unless client_request_total offset 5m)`

Comment: Many thanks @markalex for your help.
Your suggestion perfectly meets my needs.

Here is the query used in the end:

**count(group by (id) (changes(client_request_total[5m])>0 or (client_request_total unless client_request_total offset 5m)))**